# How does PGF/TikZ work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How has it been possible to develop a huge vector graphics package, PGF/TikZ, entirely within the TeX language? Exactly how is it working under the hood? Which techniques and TeX primitives does it rely on to produce its graphical output in my TeX document?

Comment: PGF relies on `\special`, with drivers for each engine used for producing the final output, so `dvips`, `(x)dvipdfmx`, `pdftex` and `luatex`. The higher level graphic commands are translated into lower level `\special` commands tailored for the used engine.

Comment: You can find the implementation of the drivers in the files [`pgfsys-<driver>.def`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/tex).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Let's look at a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tracingmacros=1
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\tracingmacros=1` instruction will show all macro expansions in the log file.

Compiling with `latex` we find

```
\pgfsys@invoke #1->\special {ps:: #1}
#1<-0.0 0.0 moveto 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\special {ps:: #1}
#1<-28.3468 28.3468 lineto 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\special {ps:: #1}
#1<-pgfstr
```

With `pdflatex` we find

```
\pgfsys@invoke #1->\pdfliteral {#1}
#1<-0.0 0.0 m 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\pdfliteral {#1}
#1<-28.3468 28.3468 l 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\pdfliteral {#1}
#1<-S
```

With `xelatex`, we see

```
\pgfsys@invoke #1->\special {pdf:code #1}
#1<-0.0 0.0 m 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\special {pdf:code #1}
#1<-28.3468 28.3468 l 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\special {pdf:code #1}
#1<-S
```

Finally, `lualatex` (with LuaTeX v. 0.90), produces

```
\pgfsys@invoke #1->\pdfextension literal{#1}
#1<-0.0 0.0 m 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\pdfextension literal{#1}
#1<-28.3468 28.3468 l 

\pgfsys@invoke #1->\pdfextension literal{#1}
#1<-S
```

Higher level graphic commands are translated into lower level ones, but different for each engine used. PGF has various drivers and loads the relevant one, which provides the translations specially tailored for the used engine.

The primitive `\special` simply writes its argument to the DVI (or XDV) file and it's a duty of `dvips` or `xdvipdfmx` to use this code for providing a graphic rendering. With `pdftex` there is `\pdfliteral` that writes PDF code to the PDF file and the same for `luatex`, just with a different name.

Dealing with each possible graphic command would require a book. Look at the files

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf-via-dvi.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-svg.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvi.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfm.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvisvgm.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-tex4ht.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-textures.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-vtex.def
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
```

for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, an extremely minor detail: Your list suggests that you are using TL16. In that case, shouldn’t it be LuaTeX v. 0.95?

Comment: @Gaussler The change was in v. 0.90

Comment: Also, with the `mplib` library in LuaTeX, I think it is not entirely unlikely that PGF might slowly develop into a partial front-end to `metapost`, at least when compiled using LuaTeX.

Comment: @Gaussler I don't think this is feasible, but who knows?

Comment: You wrote: "it's a duty of dvips or xdvipdfmx to use this code for providing a graphic rendering." How are divps and xdvipdfmx supposed to know what to do with the literal `pgfstr` which, according to your example, is output when compiled with `latex`? `pgfstr` is not a PostScript command.

Comment: @EvanAad The graphic interface in LaTeX is responsible to pass the correct commands in the `\special` (or similar feature), as shown in the answer.