# Footprints symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, packages

I was wondering if someone knows if there is a foot/feet symbol available in any of latex packages that I could use in my text? I would appreciate any hint.

I do really mean a foot/feet icon as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: The tikz decoration library has something similar

Comment: Ti*k*Z has footprints in the library `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}`.

Answer (score 26):

Welcome to the Ti*k*Z section of TeX.SE!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={footprints,foot length=20pt}] 
\draw [decorate] (0,0) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: A version for tikzlings. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {human,gnome,bird,felis silvestris}
{\begin{scope}[xshift=2.25*\Y*1cm,decoration={footprints,foot length=20pt,foot of=\X}] 
\draw [decorate] (0,0) -- (0,1.3);
\node[font=\sffamily] at (0,1.5) {\X};
\end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd ADDENDUM**: How to create your custom footprints? I assume you have some black/white picture of a left foot, which you can legally use for that.

1. Convert this picture to the pnm format. For instance, on Linux/Mac
   OS you can use `pngtopnm pic.png >pic.pnm`.
2. Then use (e.g.) `potrace` to make it a vector image, `potrace pic.pnm`.
3. You can open that with `inkscape` and save it as `tex`, which
   yields a document in the pstricks format. Remove the preamble and end.
4. Next you only need to do a regex search and replace that convers
   converts `\curveto` to `\pgfpathcurveto`, similarly for `\lineto` and
   `\moveto`. And a coordinate `(x,y)` needs to become
   `{\pgfqpoint{xpt}{ypt}}` (the outer braces are important).
5. Then get rid of all `\newrgbcolor`, `\pscustom` and `\newpath`
   statements and extra braces, but end all paths with `\pgfpathclose`.

Finally wrap this into

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgf@lib@foot@of@critter{
  % Coordinates extracted from 
  % license... Unknown author.
  % 
  % Flip and rotate
  \pgftransformcm{0}{-1}{1}{0}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.8pt}}
  \pgftransformscale{0.005}      

  <result of your conversion>

\makeatother
```

Of course, you may have to adjust the transformations, e.g. by dialing a different scale factor in `\pgftransformscale{0.005}`.
You can then access these foot prints by saying `foot of=critter`. I will be happy to supplement this by an explicit example if someone points me to an image of a foot print that is free to use.

Comment: SUPER!Just what I was looking for!

Comment: -1, as no marmot prints:-)

Comment: @marmot Would it help to have the coordinates as tikz code? (I can convert from vector graphic to tikz, but no idea how to get the raw pgf code)

Comment: @marmot: Your `potrace` suggestion is similar to this: [Adding a signature on an online job application](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764)

Comment: @Werner The potrace part, yes, not the (IMHO important) part on converting the resulting eps to pgf, which was implicitly asked by [samcarter in this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450269/foot-feet-symbol-in-latex/450270?noredirect=1#comment1131770_450270). Do you agree?

Comment: @marmot Thanks a lot for the potrace conversion guide!

Comment: @samcarter potrace may not even be essential here, I think, one may do it just with inkscape. The reason why I added this was to provide a way of converting to the pgf syntax, which so many seem to be afraid of. ;-)

Comment: @marmot If I remember correctly, inkscape itself uses potrace to trace images -- I just used it as catchy name for the summary. The interesting thing is that pstricks can so easily be converted into pgf. This is something new to me.

Comment: @samcarter Not too surprising given [how Ti*k*Z/pgf works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314209/121799)... ;-)

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the link! Interesting to read!

Comment: Beyond the 4 kinds of footprints, are there other choices? where do i find the list?

Answer (score 17):

A version for when it's cold in the winter and one needs shoes (a problem unknown to marmots, because they hibernate):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faIcon{shoe-prints} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fontawesome5.sty is not available with Miktex 2.9. Where can I download this package?

Comment: @pzorba75 https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5?lang=en says it is also available for miktex

Comment: Available out of Miktex. To be installed manually not automatically on the fly when compiling with Texmaker and Miktex.