# Converting Tikz code to PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape, pgfornament

I would like to convert an SVG image (from inkscape) into PGF so that I can call the image using `include package{pgfornaments}`.

Using svg2tikz (Save As > Latex with PStricks and Save As > Tikz code), but I cannot figure out how to convert that output to PGF code that can be used by pgfornaments.

Is there a converter that will strip out the Tikz front-end and render PGF code? 
Or, are there settings in Export > Export to Tikz path that will render as PGF code?

Sample of my output (as Tikz code)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[rotate around={90.0:(189.94021,85.82203)}]
  \path[draw=black,fill=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.032pt]
    (137.4186,46.0503) .. controls (137.5137,51.9889) and (137.1626,63.2730) ..
    (137.5933,63.9338) .. controls (137.8673,64.4875) and (137.9942,64.6226) ..
    (138.9748,64.9034) .. controls (140.2243,65.1767) and (143.6854,65.3049) ..
    (144.1519,64.9899) .. controls (144.5977,64.6890) and (144.8841,61.4342) ..
    (144.9169,61.2122) .. controls (145.0740,56.9180) and (145.2158,53.4952) ..
```

Sample of my code (PStricks)

```
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: inkscape 0.92.3
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(256,245.44000244)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(229.711937,212.13954244)
\curveto(223.773378,212.04444244)(212.489203,212.39554244)(211.828455,211.96491244)
\curveto(211.274754,211.69091244)(211.139625,211.56395244)(210.858804,210.58342244)
\curveto(210.585535,209.33391244)(210.457387,205.87276244)(210.772344,205.40625244)
\curveto(211.073258,204.96053244)(214.328044,204.67404244)(214.550021,204.64133244)
\curveto(218.844224,204.48414244)(222.267088,204.34241244)(227.607715,203.61839244)
\lineto(207.616746,203.61797244)
\curveto(208.805053,204.30850244)(209.063802,204.48101244)(209.929411,205.00819244)
\lineto(209.713273,213.36042244)
\curveto(209.714773,214.08932244)(209.696303,214.16726244)(209.956956,214.55688244)
\curveto(210.159345,214.82979244)(210.407771,215.07556244)(210.988481,215.12536244)
\curveto(221.851601,214.49965244)(226.399447,213.03761244)(229.711932,212.13972244)
\closepath
}
```

Sample of vectorian pgfornaments

```
\m 21.8584 19.4822 
\c 24.1677 19.4822 29.308 19.6707 34.9033 21.0996 
\c 40.4978 22.5278 42.8549 24.837 42.8549 26.074 
\c 42.8549 27.3123 39.8551 28.5492 36.6661 28.0028 
\c 33.4758 27.455 32.6657 26.3602 32.6657 25.7168 
\c 32.6657 25.0747 33.57 24.5269 34.2612 25.0262
```

Comment: I believe there is an automatic solution but if not you merely need to convert \curveto to \pgfpathcurveto and round brackets to curly ones.

Comment: The detailed instructions of that can be found under [second addendum in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450270/121799).

Comment: To convert arbitrary TikZ paths into pgfornament commands , the  `show path construction` decoration (p.634, pgfmanual, v3.1.1) may be useful...

Comment: use the `save path` key from the intersections library to save the underlying path, then show the macro in the log, or just use it directly.