# Tikz "line" with footsteps style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is it possible to make a line style in tikz, similar to dotted or dashed,
such that instead the decoration is a series of footsteps,
as in the figure below?
The footsteps do not need to be as complicated, but they should be recognizable as such.

[image: footsteps]

Comment: See *decorations.footprints* library, TikZ & PGF manual, v 3.1.5b, pp. 651-652.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450270.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footprints symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450269/footprints-symbol-in-latex)